# What is the expected number of people who are shorter than both of their immediate neighbors?

Tags: probability

A total of n people randomly take their seats around a circular table with n chairs. No two people have the same height. What is the expected number of people who are shorter than both of their immediate neighbors?

It is all I have and I dont know how to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n\ge 3$.  Number the seats from $1$ to $n$. Define indicator random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$ by  $X_i=1$ if the person in seat $i$ is shorter than her two neighbours, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise. We want to find $E(X_1+\cdots+X_n)$.  By the linearity of expectation this is $E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_n)$.

We have $\Pr(X_i=1)=\frac{1}{3}$, and therefore $E(X_i)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_n)=\frac{n}{3}$.

Comment: why we have $E(XX_{1})$

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo.

Answer (score 3):

Pick a person. Among that person and the two  neighbours, exactly one is the most vertically challenged. The probability that it is the initially picked person is $\frac13$ simply by symmetry. Hence the expected number is $\frac n3$ (assuming $n\ge 3$).

Comment: Why should "the most vertically challenged" be synonymous of "the shortest"?  (+1 for the maths answer.)